# Get UITextField Data from Separate .XIB - Swift/XCode

Tags: ios, swift

Here are the binaries:

**FieldStyle1.swift**:

```
import UIKit

protocol FieldStyle1Delegate {
    func textChange(text: String, tag: NSInteger)
}

class FieldStyle1: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var delegate: FieldStyle1Delegate?
    @IBOutlet var fullnameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var confirmPasswordField: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        fullnameField.delegate = self
        usernameField.delegate = self
        emailField.delegate = self
        passwordField.delegate = self
        confirmPasswordField.delegate = self

        fullnameField.tag = 0
        usernameField.tag = 1
        emailField.tag = 2
        passwordField.tag = 3
        confirmPasswordField.tag = 4

    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        delegate?.textChange(text: textField.text!, tag: textField.tag)

    }

}
```

I need to pull the  `@IBOutlet var passwordField: UITextField!` and `@IBOutlet var fullnameField: UITextField!` from `FieldStyle1.swift`, into the `ViewController.swift` create a user function, where

`user.username = usernameField.text`, but im getting the "use of unresolved identifier "usernameField" error.

Ive tried multiple methods found on stackoverflow but all have been unsuccessful. Please help!

Comment: Can you show the relevant code parts of your file `ViewController.swift `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access directly from textFields from table cell So you need to implement protocols as you implemented:

First of all, you need to give FieldStyle1Delegate from the controller to table cell like this way:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"identifier") as? FieldStyle1 else {
            fatalError("Nil")
        }
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
```

Then you need to handle it in view controller and get data from table cell:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FieldStyle1Delegate {

func textChange(text: String, tag: NSInteger) {
     if tag == 0 {
        user.fullname = text
     } else if tag == 1 {
        user.username = text
     } else if tag == 2 {
       user.email = text
     } else if tag == 3 {
       user.password = text
     }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) When configuring a cell you must assign object that conforms to your `FieldStyle1Delegate` delegate. If you are configuring cell in you view controller you can assign `self`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = ...
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

2) You must conform to that delegate:

```
class ViewController: FieldStyle1Delegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func textChange(text: String, tag: NSInteger) {
        // now you have those values
    }

}
```

Full example:

```
class ViewController: FieldStyle1Delegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return ...
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = ...
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func textChange(text: String, tag: NSInteger) {
        // now you have those values
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hold reference of FieldStyle1 class in viewController.swift

```
Class ViewController: UIViewController {
 var xibView:  FieldStyle1?

 func loadNib() {
   self.xibView = //..load nib
}

func accessOutlets() {
  User.name = xibView?.textField.text 
}

}
```